# Which command can be used to connect to Okuma controller from PC based app? I dont see any function in help section open sdk api for okuma

Tags: okuma

i dont see connection method or command to connect PC app which can connect to okuma controller. The reference Help section is used of SDK from github provided by okuma america

tried code like **connecttonc** but it is not available with existing DLL files